# Can I track if someone clicked a link on my Twitter post

Tags: api, twitter, hyperlink, twitter-api-v2

I have a private business Twitter account and I would like to know when someone clicks **any link** inside one of my posts. This solution cannot assume that we know the form of the link being posted.

For example a twitter post like this:

> Have you guys heard of this amazing site called [google](https://www.google.com)?

I would like to see how many people clicked on this google.com link. I don't need to know any specific information about who they are, just if it was clicked or not.

Ideally I would want this from the API but crawlers and plugins are also possible. I would like to avoid using a paid tool but those would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have multiple choices:

1. Use google [firebase or google analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics)
2. Create your own short link services by python or any other programming languages.
3. Just search in the google and look for short link generators which gives appropriate service.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The solution must be able to track link clicks from any link in any form. Sadly, I cannot ensure that these links are in short form due to not knowing what our clients will post.

Answer (score 1):

Hi using the twitter api you should be able to understand how many clicks a link has.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics

But to have all this info automated you might need to use a third-party tool.
This should be the most straight forward solution.